# Finding Poles of an RC Op-Amp Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I am not sure how to get started with this practice question:

[image]

I think to find the poles I need the transfer function, but I'm not sure how to analyse this circuit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go back to your course material. It will explain what a pole is. Don't ask us as a way to avoid reading your textbook.

Comment: Our lecture notes are extremely vague and unhelpful. I always search my notes, google, and look for similar questions on this site before asking. Please don't make rude assumptions.

Comment: so Poles are a foreign subject?  I think it has something to do with the x,y axis or the 'z' plane  z= x+ jy but I can't recall ever using this method except in school

Comment: http://www.thepoles.com/

Comment: It's a Sallen-Key low pass filter. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology#Application:_Low-pass_filter and http://www.daycounter.com/Filters/SallenKeyLP/Sallen-Key-LP-Filter-Design-Equations.phtml

Comment: "Please don't make rude assumptions." The alternative assumption is that your course is conpletely incompetent and a waste of time. If it actually asks  you to calculate the location of poles but never tells you what poles are, - well, that implies a rude assumption too - that the professor is a blithering incompetent and you need to drop the course immediately. My money is on the first assumption, which in turn is based on the non-rude assumption that the school you are going to is not a rapacious, exploitative institution. I could be wrong, of course. If so, find another school. Now.

Comment: The professor IS incompetent. He's a 'research professor' - minimum effort towards his students, only interested in getting papers published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct - for identifying the poles you need the transfer function. This function can be calculated by yourself using one of the classical methods for analyzing opamp-based feedback amplifiers. In this case, I would propose to use the information that for an ideal opamp with unity feedback the differential input voltage vd=(vp-vn) across the opamp input nodes is zero. Hence vp=vn. Hint: For both voltages you need to apply the superposition rule.